# Deadlock testing with TestSchedulers, Rx and BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive, blockingcollection

I have the following class which basically subscribes to an **int** observable and multiplies the value by 2. For reality purposes I added a Thread.Sleep to simulate a heavy processing.

```
public class WorkingClass
{
    private BlockingCollection<int> _collection = new BlockingCollection<int>(1);

    public WorkingClass(IObservable<int> rawValues)
    {
        rawValues.Subscribe(x => _collection.Add(x));
    }

    public IObservable<int> ProcessedValues()
    {
        return Observable.Create<int>(observer =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int value;

                try
                {
                    value = _collection.Take();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    observer.OnError(ex);
                    break;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000); //Simulate long work
                observer.OnNext(value * 2);
            }

            return Disposable.Empty;
        });
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble testing it, in the following test I just want to assert that if the source stream emits the value 1 the SUT will emit the value 2:

```
[Test]
public void SimpleTest()
{
    var sourceValuesScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var newThreadScheduler = new TestScheduler();

    var source = sourceValuesScheduler.CreateHotObservable(
         new Recorded<Notification<int>>(1000, Notification.CreateOnNext(1)));

    var sut = new WorkingClass(source);

    var observer = sourceValuesScheduler.CreateObserver<int>();

    sut.ProcessedValues()
        .SubscribeOn(newThreadScheduler) //The cold part (i.e, the while loop) of the ProcessedValues Observable should run in a different thread
        .Subscribe(observer);

    sourceValuesScheduler.AdvanceTo(1000);

    observer.Messages.AssertEqual(new Recorded<Notification<int>>(1000, Notification.CreateOnNext(2)));
}
```

If I run this test the assert fails because the newThreadScheduler was never started and consequently the ProcessedValues observable was never created. If I do this:

```
 sourceValuesScheduler.AdvanceTo(1000);
 newThreadScheduler.AdvanceTo(1000);
```

It doesn't work either because the newThreadScheduler uses the same Thread of the sourceValuesScheduler so the test will be hanging right after the processed value is emmited, at the line:

```
value = _collection.Take();
```

Is there a way we can have multiple TestSchedulers running on different threads? Otherwise how can I test classes like this?

Comment: If ever you use `return Disposable.Empty;` to end an `Observable.Create` then you are creating an observable that can display all sorts of concurrency issues. You should never return `return Disposable.Empty;`.

Comment: What happens when you try this code: `public IObservable<int> ProcessedValues() => _collection.GetConsumingEnumerable().ToObservable();` ?

Comment: I didn't know we should not use Disposable.Empty, are you saying that we should never use Observable.Create when there's nothing to dispose?
Your suggestion of using _collection.GetConsumingEnumerable().ToObservable() causes a deadlock, because the processing has to be done in a different thread. On my example I was using a second scheduler, however the accepted answer uses the Task.Factory.StartNew(...). The problem is that it doesn't work when the Thread.Sleep is replaced by an await Task.Delay

Comment: When you use `Disposable.Empty` then the observable will have ended before the subscription has completed. That's what causes deadlocks. It's a bad anti-pattern to return it. I'll have a rethink of my suggestion, but I can't do that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Take()` blocks until there is an item to remove from the `BlockingCollection<int>` or you call `CompleteAdding()` on it.

Given your current implementation, the thread on which you subscribe to `ProcessedValues()` and execute the `while` loop will never finish.

You are supposed to consume the `BlockingCollection<int>` on a separate thread. You may for example create a consume `Task` when `ProcessedValues()` is called. Consider the following implementation which also disposes the `BlockingCollection<int>`:

```
public sealed class WorkingClass : IDisposable
{
    private BlockingCollection<int> _collection = new BlockingCollection<int>(1);
    private List<Task> _consumerTasks = new List<Task>();

    public WorkingClass(IObservable<int> rawValues)
    {
        rawValues.Subscribe(x => _collection.Add(x));
    }

    public IObservable<int> ProcessedValues()
    {
        return Observable.Create<int>(observer =>
        {
            _consumerTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Consume(observer), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });
    }

    private void Consume(IObserver<int> observer)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (int value in _collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); //Simulate long work
                observer.OnNext(value * 2);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            observer.OnError(ex);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _collection.CompleteAdding();
        Task.WaitAll(_consumerTasks.ToArray());
        _collection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

It can be tested like using the following code:

```
var sourceValuesScheduler = new TestScheduler();

var source = sourceValuesScheduler.CreateHotObservable(
    new Recorded<Notification<int>>(1000, Notification.CreateOnNext(1)));

var observer = sourceValuesScheduler.CreateObserver<int>();

using (var sut = new WorkingClass(source))
{
    sourceValuesScheduler.AdvanceTo(1000); //add to collection
    sut.ProcessedValues().Subscribe(observer); //consume
} //...and wait until the loop exists

observer.Messages.AssertEqual(new Recorded<Notification<int>>(1000, Notification.CreateOnNext(2)));
```

Comment: Do you know how to make it work if instead of a 'Thread.Sleep(1000)' we have an 'await Task.Delay(1000)'. The changes would be: private async Task Consume(IObserver<int> observer) and 'Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await Consume(observer)...'

Comment: @EduardoBrites: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.